# Work done by a body moving in a cicular path

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, work, centripetal-force

My book has a question:

> A man is running along a circular path of radius $7$ m and comes to rest after travelling a distance of $45$ m. What is the work done by the man?

The options are

> (a)$>0$ (b)$<0$ (c)$=0$ (d)None of the above

The answer given is:

> (c) $=0$  $\because \cos\theta=\cos 90=0$.

But shouldn't the answer be (a)$>0$?

Thats because the circumference of the path is $2×\pi ×7=44$ m  and he travels $45$ m *along the circular path*. So his net displacement is obviously $>0$.

Also, the $\cos 90=0$ logic doesn't apply here right? Since no centripetal force acts on the person, and he changes the direction of the force exerted by his muscles at every instant, which is in the direction of displacement itself. What i mean to say is there is no force pulling a running man in a circular path towards the centre, so we can't apply this logic either, right?

Comment: This is an excellent example of a TERRIBLE question.  Work is defined as force x distance, but only the component of force that is parallel to the displacement is involved in work.  That is the concept the question was implying, but the man has to use muscular force against friction to push off of some surface, and at each step, he is moving parallel to the friction force that is propelling him.

Comment: @DavidWhite So the book wanted us to think it more simply I guess. Terrible question indeed

Comment: "The work done by the man" is meaningless to start with. The work is done by a specific force so if you don't specify the force there is no way to answer the question. It is not how much energy is used by the body to do this motion but how much work.

Comment: A boy throws a 1 kg rock. What color is the stoplight? That's as good a question as the one in your book.

Comment: @BillN Lol that cracked me up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since no centripetal force acts on the person

If the person is running in a circle there is a centripetal force acting on that person. It is the static friction force that the ground exerts on the runners feet. Since the centripetal force is always acting perpendicular to the runners displacement, the *physics work* done by the centripetal force on the runner is zero.

I stress "physics work" because that doesn't mean the runner isn't  expending energy during running (burning calories converting chemical potential energy into work done by the muscles) to enable circular motion. But that's not physics work. An example is holding a heavy object without lifting it. It stresses the muscles but since there is no displacement there is no physics work done. The same applies to pushing on a wall without moving it. The energy expended is internal.

Richard Feynman in his physics lectures explains it this way in connection with holding but not lifting a heavy weight:

*The fact that we have to generate effort to hold up a weight is simply due to to the design of striated muscle. What happens is when a nerve impulse reaches a muscle fiber, the fiber gives a little twitch and then relaxes, so that when we hold something up , enormous volleys of nerve impulses are coming in to the muscle, large numbers of twitches are maintaining the weight, while other fibers relax. When we hold a heavy weight we get tired, begin to shake, ...because the muscle is tired and not reacting fast enough.*

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good answer. I would add that there is another force besides centripetal force. This force slows him to a stop. It acts in the opposite direction to his motion. $\vec F \cdot \vec d < 0$.

Comment: @mmesser314 Good point. But if we consider that the runner stars at rest then an equal amount of positive work would have been  needed to get up to speed for a net work of zero.

Answer (score 0):

The question suggests that the man is not exerting the force in the direction he is running. His muscles are produce the centripetal force towards the center, which is what's turning him constantly. Since the force is perpendicular to the displacement the $cos\ 90^o = 0$ logic holds.

I don't think this accurately describes the physics in real life, but it's what the textbook wants.

Comment: "His muscles are producing the centripetal force towards the centre" that's not the case in real life right? My book wants us to just *consider* that for this problem then?